# Write to multiple tables using data obtained from a view in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm new to SQL and I have a large database that needs some cleanup. The way it is formatted is like this:  each table has a column containing an ID number and a second column containing some other type of information like so.

1. Names: ID# Name
2. Emails: ID# Email
3. Phones: ID# Phone
4. Notes: ID# Note

I have a view that shows the information from all of these tables (in the actual database there are about 90 of them) and some code that takes each 'Note' and processes it into its individual components.  The notes are basically a jumble of all the other information combined, with a typical note reading:

```
First M. Last, Position Title, Phone 123-456-7890, Email abc@def.com
```

What I have now is code that iterates over all the notes in the view (~3 million) and identifies each element (phone, email, etc), but now I need to take these elements and write them to their respective columns in the other tables in the database.  I know that you can't write to a view as you can to a table and I'm not sure what the best strategy is for this seeing as I have so many notes to process. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you *can* write to a view if you define an appropriate `DO INSTEAD` trigger (newer Pg versions) or `RULE` (older versions).

In this case, though, I'd recommend extracting the data from the view that you wish to change into a new table (`UNLOGGED` if using PostgreSQL 9.1+). I'd then write a series of `UPDATE ... FROM` statements, one for each table to be updated, that join against the change info table.

If that's not viable, another way that's much slower but more amenible to being done in small chunks is to do it with a PL/PgSQL procedure, where you grab a few rows from the view or a temp table created from the view, update them in all associated tables, grab a few more rows, and repeat.